# Linking error: undefined reference within the same class

Tags: c++, class, include

I am getting the following error with g++ 4.9:

```
basis.cpp:16: undefined reference to `Basis::foo(int, int)'
```

This is the header file:

```
#ifndef BASIS_H
#define BASIS_H


#include "common.h"
#include <math.h>
#include "xdouble.h"

using namespace std;

class Basis {

private:

    int rank;
    int dim;



public:

    Basis(); //Empty constructor

    Basis(int r, int d); //Default constructor

    void foo(int a, int b);
    void bar(int a, int b);
};

#endif
```

The basis.cpp file is the following:

```
#include "basis.h"

Basis::Basis()
{
    rank = 0;
    dim = 0;
}

Basis::Basis(int r, int d) // Default constructor
{
    rank = r;
    dim = d;

}

void Basis::bar(int a, int b)
{
    void foo(int a, int b);
}

void Basis::foo(int a, int b)
{

}
```

Even though I'm including the basis.h file I get the undefined reference error and I can't understand why this is happening. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You probably missed to link `basis.cpp` with your executable.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this seems like a compile time error though, from looking at the error message. But it is not reproducible from the code above, even removing the `foo` function declaration in `Basis::bar()` and replacing it by a function call.

Comment: Are you getting a compile time error or a linker error? From your error message it looks like a compile time error, but in the title you say linker error.

Comment: All files are compiled. Only at the end when the executable is to be created I get this error. So, I assume that this is a linker error

Comment: can you put the commands you use to compile it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a copy and paste error. Try this:

```
void Basis::bar(int a, int b)
{
  foo(a, b);
}
```

You made a mistake because you copied and pasted the definition of the function foo in the place where you wanted to call this function.

Comment: Adding a simple explaination about when you removed within your answer would be helpful.

Comment: I don't know what can I write... fc67 made a mistake, because he (or she) copied and pasted definition of function foo in place where he wants to call this function.

Comment: That would be useful to include in your answer